# Linked assembly subroutine doesn't work as expected

Tags: linux, assembly, ld, system-calls, fasm

I'm writing a simple subroutine in FASM to print 32-bit unsigned integers to STDOUT. This is what I came up with:

```
format elf
public uprint

section ".text" executable
uprint:
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx
    push esi
    mov  ebx, 10
    mov  ecx, buf + 11
    xor  esi, esi
do:
    dec ecx
    xor edx, edx
    div ebx
    add dl, 0x30
    mov [ecx], dl
    inc esi
    test eax, 0
    jnz do
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, esi
    int 0x80
    pop esi
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    ret

section ".data" writeable
    buf rb 11
```

Then I wrote another program to test whether the above subroutine works properly:

```
format elf
extrn uprint
public _start

section ".text" executable
_start:
    mov eax, 1337
    call uprint
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, newline
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80

section ".data"
    newline db 0x0A
```

I compiled both these programs to their corresponding object files and linked them to create the executable.

On executing the program however it only displayed `7` instead of `1337`. As it turns out only the last digit of the number is display regardless of the number itself.

<strike>This is strange because my `uprint` subroutine is correct. In fact if I combine both these programs into a single program then it displays `1337` correctly.</strike>

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you turn run it in a debugger and see what's the content of eax on the beginning of uprint ?

Comment: @Mellowcandle - I have no clue how to debug FASM programs. Is it possible to use GDB with FASM?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible with GDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my mistake. I'm using `test eax, 0` which always sets the zero flag. Hence only the first digit is processed. Intead I need to use either `test eax, eax` or `cmp eax, 0`.

Comment: I am not convinced. If you were using exactly the same routine for `uprint` when you combined the two into one module, as `test eax, 0`  always sets the zero flag the `jnz do` would have found `Z` set after processing the first digit, so it should never have produced `1337` - but you say it did. Something not adding up here...

Comment: @PeterWright - Indeed. I don't remember what I did the first time around, but I believe I used `cmp eax, 0` (which is why it worked). Then when I created a separate test program I changed the `cmp` to `test` to save on computer cycles. -_-

Answer (score 0):

I gain the distinct impression that your LINK operation is building the `uprint` before the `_start` and you're in fact entering `UPRINT`, not at `_start` as you expect.